# Setup Nginx reverse-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, self-hosting

I am absolutely new to the selfhosting community I want to setup a home server that grants access to different applications. Using docker I got a wordpress and a nextcloud app up and running. Now I want to add bitwarden and want it to be accessible via vault.myhosting.xx. Later I want to add ssl via letsencrypt.

I am using jwilder/nginx-proxy which makes it very easy to add new virtual host by doing minor changes in the docker-compose.yml of the specific app.

I wanted to do the same in bitwarden (I had some bugs when editing the docker-compose.yml see [issue:188](https://github.com/bitwarden/core/issues/188)). The bitwarden developer suggested adjusting the reverse-proxy. But I do not know how to do this. I tried to implement a new virtual host in the reverse-proxy container but I do not understand how to do the linking to the bitwarden container.

Answer (score 0):

A warring! English is not native for me. Im not sure that understand your problem exactly.

### How it's work in approximation:

Any domain name is a real IP address alias.

Special NS servers (DNS) keep this pair domain-IP.
When any user enter the address it reffers to DNS.
DNS may be public like a GoogleDNS (8.8.8.8), or specific for internet provider.

### How docker work:

Docker in out of the box use severals drivers to network connections:
bridge, host, null, overlay...

For example bridge:

- Your machine with Docker it is HOST
- Any Containers can there port provide to host port

In Docker-compose its look like
`.yaml
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80`

Its mean that host port 8080 will be alias to 80 port of container. Only one application in each time can listen specific port. If you try add one more it will crush container up process. So use different port. For port less then 1024 you may need root access.

Now when app provide port. You may access on address like localhost:8080

If you need access from internet to this port you may meet next problem:

### After that problems

1) Switch NAT -> most of switch have setting to open host port to internet. Way is specific by each Vendor, but not very hard to set up.

2) Dynamic IP -> it may to resolving with service like http://GoDaddy.com , http://noip.com . Also you may to buy a domain name.

Also read or watch about "docker network"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Though my problem is a little bit more specific. 

I use s.th. similar to noip. It hosts
nextcloud.myhosting.xx
wordpress.myhosting.xx
and I have registered
vault.myhosting.xx
Bitwarden is listening on 192.xxx.0.xxx:81. My nginx-reverse proxy shall redirect vault.myhosting.xx to that specific ip:port configuration. For nextcloud+wordpress I use the VIRTUAL_HOST flag in docker-compose.yml  this is not the way to go according to the developer of bitwarden. He suggests installing a virtual-host in the nginx-reverse. The question is how to achieve this.